# I can't get the attachments I added in the new mail

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Attachments are not visible after adding attachment in outlook web addin, but I can get attachments in the inbox mail -
first picture: no problem second picture :  does not appear in the new mail]
[image: no problem]

[image: does not appear in the new mail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is only supported on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The [officejs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentdetails?view=outlook-js-preview) says that attachments are only accessible in Read mode.

Comment: There are some things that you can do with attachments in Compose mode with some documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form. However I still don't think you can retrieve the current attachments in Compose.